# How to disable vote button for a product review if ID of that review exists in local storage?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, local-storage

I have list of reviews for some products in a React app. For every review user can vote is it helpful or not. Every product can have multiple reviews. When user votes, the vote button for that specific review should get disabled. I am storing Id's of clicked reviews in local storage in array, as objects with reviewId key and a value of that review Id.

This is helper file for storing and getting reviews array into React component.

```
const reviewsStorage = window.localStorage;

export const setReview = (reviewId) => {
    if (process.browser) {
        let data = [];
        const voteId = {};

        if (reviewsStorage.getItem('vote') === null || reviewsStorage.getItem('vote') === undefined) {
            voteId.reviewId = reviewId;
            data.push(voteId);
            reviewsStorage.setItem('vote', JSON.stringify(data));
        } else {
            data = JSON.parse(reviewsStorage.getItem('vote'));
            voteId.reviewId = reviewId;
            data.push(voteId);
            reviewsStorage.setItem('vote', JSON.stringify(data));
        }
    }
};

export const getReview = () => {
    if (process.browser) {
        const votes = JSON.parse(reviewsStorage.getItem('vote'));
        return votes;
    }
};
```

In my component I have feedbackSubmit function which when fired is calling setReview function from helper file which sets an array of object, and then I am storing that array in vts variable.

vts variable is structure like this:

```
[
  {
    reviewId: "746374"
  },
  {
    reviewId: "725364"
  }
]
```

jsx for this component with buttons:

```
const ReviewsCard = ({ reviews }) => {
    const reviewCard = reviews.map((review, index) => {
        const {
            UserNickname,
            UserLocation,
            Title,
            Rating,
            ReviewText,
            Id } = review;

        const feedbackSubmit = (e) => {
            e.preventDefault();
            setReview(Id);
            const vts = getReview();
            console.log(vts);
        };

        return (
            <div className="review-items" key={index}>
                <div className="item">
                    <p className="user-nickname">{UserNickname}</p>
                    <p className="user-location">User location: {UserLocation}</p>
                </div>
                <div className="item center">
                    <p className="title">{Title}</p>
                    <RatingStars
                        showRatingsLabel={true}
                        averageRating={Rating}
                    />
                    <p className="review-text">{ReviewText}</p>

                        <div className="feedback">
                            <p>Was this review helpful?</p>
                            <button onClick={feedbackSubmit} type="button" disabled={false}>
                                <img
                                    data-vote="Positive"
                                    className="positive-feedback-icon"
                                    src="../static/icons/green.png"
                                    alt="positive-feedback-icon"
                                />
                                {Id}
                            </button>
                            <button onClick={feedbackSubmit} type="button" disabled={false}>
                                <img
                                    data-vote="Negative"
                                    className="negative-feedback-icon"
                                    src="../static/icons/red.png"
                                    alt="negative-feedback-icon"
                                />
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    )}
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    });

    return (
        <>
            {reviewCard}
        </>
    );
};
```

Now every time that this component is loaded I wish to check if an Id of one of the reviews which are rendered is in vts array and if it is I would like to disable button which belongs to that specific review.

I am new to React and this kind of stuff for storing and checking values in local storage so if someone could help, or give me an idea how this can be done?

Answer (score 1):

You could create a `state` `isReviewd` to hold the status of the review , then in `useEffect` get all the reviews from the localStorage and filter it with the current review id and set the `isReviewd` state according to the filter result.

If filter returns result then disable the button otherwise enable.

**Sample code:**

```
const ReviewsCard = ({ reviews }) => {
  const reviewCard = reviews.map((review, index) => {
    const [isReviewd, setIsReviewes] = useState(true);
    const [reviewed, setReviewed] = useState([]);

    const {
      UserNickname,
      UserLocation,
      Title,
      Rating,
      ReviewText,
      Id } = review;

    useEffect(() => {
      const vts = getReview();
      const checkReview = vts.filter(review => review.reviewId === Id);
      if (checkReview.length > 0) {
        setIsReviewes(true);
      }
    }, [reviewed]);


    const feedbackSubmit = (e) => {
      e.preventDefault();
      setReview(Id);
      const vts = getReview();
      setReviewed(vts);
      console.log(vts);
    };
    return (
      <div className="review-items" key={index}>
        <div className="item">
          <p className="user-nickname">{UserNickname}</p>
          <p className="user-location">User location: {UserLocation}</p>
        </div>
        <div className="item center">
          <p className="title">{Title}</p>
          <RatingStars
            showRatingsLabel={true}
            averageRating={Rating}
          />
          <p className="review-text">{ReviewText}</p>
          <div className="feedback">
            <p>Was this review helpful?</p>
            <button onClick={feedbackSubmit} type="button" disabled={isReviewd}>
              <img
                data-vote="Positive"
                className="positive-feedback-icon"
                src="../static/icons/green.png"
                alt="positive-feedback-icon"
              />
              {Id}
            </button>
            <button onClick={feedbackSubmit} type="button" disabled={isReviewd}>
              <img
                data-vote="Negative"
                className="negative-feedback-icon"
                src="../static/icons/red.png"
                alt="negative-feedback-icon"
              />
            </button>
          </div>
          )}
              </div>
      </div>
    );
  });
  return (
    <>
      {reviewCard}
    </>
  );
```